# Permission to submit webform only for the author of the node

Tags: nodes, webforms

I'm using webform 8.x for a personal project and I'd like to know if it possible to enable only the author of the node to submit the form.

In my project each node is an aquarium, and I am using webform to collect the all the daily data for that specific node ( aquarium ), like temperature, pH, KH ecc.
I was able to create a view related to the node (aquarium) where you can see the data submitted daily for that specific aquarium, but the problem is that everyone can submit the form, while I need only the author of the node to be able to submit the webform.

Can you please give me some ideas? I'm stuck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting [Allow comments only for the author of the node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293692/allow-comments-only-for-the-author-of-the-node)
 and [This book](https://books.google.it/books?id=yplGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq)
I think I can try to answer this question myself:

I made a custom module and I used [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.9.x):

here is the function:

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if($form['#webform_id'] == "YOUR-WEBFORM-ID"){
    $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
 if(!is_null($node) && $node->getOwnerId() != \Drupal::currentUser()->id()) {
     $form['#access'] = false;
 }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said if this is Drupal 7 or Drupal 8 but this should work for D8

It sounds like each author already has a user account on your website, so you can go to "Settings" on your webform and then click the "Access" tab (.e.g /admin/structure/webform/manage/FORM_MACHINE_NAME/access)

And in there you can restrict the ability to create submissions to a specific user(s) only

Comment: Thanks for your answer I`m using Drupal 8. I need this to be automatic, if I'm going to have a lot of users in this way I'll have to manually edit the webform and give permissions to each user manually.

Comment: But from the sounds of it aren't you creating a new webform each time anyway? If you wanted a slicker way of doing it you should have 1 common webform and each user is associated to a aquarium and then you could retrieve all webform submissions from a specific user with would also be their own aquarium

Comment: No, I'm not creating e new webform each time.I've created a webform and I've associated it to a content type  (called my acquariums),  when a user crete a new node ( a new acquarium), the webform appears automatically.
Through a view I intercept the data entered and filter them (using a contextual filter, id from url) so I make sure that only the data entered for that node are rendered... the problem is that now anyone who registers can see and fill the webform for nodes of which they are not authors.