# Allow comments only for the author of the node

Tags: 8, nodes, comments

I'm using Drupal 8 for a personal project and I'd like to allow only the node author to post comments.

Can you please help? I'm stuck.

Comment: Hi Alessio, do you use a custom theme or you're using a default theme ?

Comment: Hi Yusef, I made a custom theme based on bootstrap.

Comment: have you checked my latest changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although the Drupal 8 version still is on dev but you can try [comment_perm](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_perm) module.

> The Comment Permissions module enables control of commenting by user
> role and by node type. Additional user permissions for selected node
> types are added to the user access system so you can configure
> commenting with more control than Drupal core provides.

**Update**

another solution that I could suggest is using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.9.x).

in your custom module

```
function YOURMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == "YOUR_COMMENT_TYPE_ID"){
    $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
    if(!is_null($node) && $node->getOwnerId() != \Drupal::currentUser()->id()) {
      $form['#access'] = false;
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Hello, I've tried the comment_perm  module for Drupal 8, but after installing it I can't find a permmission like " only the author of the node can make comments to the node" .  I read the instructions and they say to configure the module going to Administration >> Configuration >> Comment permissions , but there is nothing to configure. May be the 8.x version is only for development?

Comment: @AlessioPellegrini I've updated my answer. try it and let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've just noticed your answer, thank you for your reply. I'm trying to understand why I don't get notifications from this site when someone answers me. I`m going to try.

Comment: @AlessioPellegrini no worries. let me know about the result ;)

Comment: Ok, I made a clean D8 install and created a custom module ( hello_world ), in the hello_world directory I`ve created hello_world.info.yml and hello_world.module . In the hello_word.module I inserted this code: [code]<?php



function hello_world_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

if($form_id == "comment"){
if($form['#node']->getOwner()->id() != \Drupal::currentUser()->id()){
  // disable form 
  $form['#access'] = false;
  }
}
}

[/code] and after clearing the cache I tried, but common users can still comment on other users' articles

Comment: @AlessioPellegrini how did you do `// disable form $form['#access'] = false;` it is a sample to tell you how you can disable it. you need to find your form emlemebnt by dump($form) ; and find out which element is your form comment field

Comment: If I remove this part the function start to work: if($form['#node']->getOwner()->id() != \Drupal::currentUser()->id()){ }, may be this part is not corretc?

Comment: @AlessioPellegrini this part check that if the owner of the node is not current user then it disable the form.

Comment: Yes, I made a test and tried to remove the submit button on my comment form, and it works, here is the working function: function hello_world_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == 'comment_comment_form') {
  


    $form['actions'][submit]['#access'] = false;

}
} But if Iinsert the part to check if the owner of the node is the current user everithing stops to work, it disappear the entire comment form for every user.

Comment: Hi @AlessioPellegrini, today I had a little time to try it by myself. I update the answer. I tried it and it works. :) .enjoy!

Comment: Thank you Yusefery, I tried and it works, but only after removing FormStateInterface  before $form_state, I really don`t know why. I really appreciate your help, I've learned something new .

Comment: I tried, but as soon as I do the upvote this message appears: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. .... my reputation is actually 13.

Comment: @AlessioPellegrini now you're 23 ;)

Comment: done , and thanks again  for your help.

Comment: @AlessioPellegrini no problem. my pleasure that could help other drupalists.